# Many to Many relationship in Room returning Empty List

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

So, i have a case on anime app where a genre can be on multiple anime and an anime can have multiple genres. So, i made it into `Many to Many Relationship` and connect them with Cross Reference using `Room Database`.

My Anime Entity:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "anime",
    indices = [Index(value = ["mal_id"], unique = true)]
)
data class AnimeBasicEntity(

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "mal_id")
    val malId: Int,

    // Other properties, not included because too long and might not related
)
```

My Genre Entity:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "genre",
    indices = [Index(value = ["mal_id"], unique = true)]
)
data class AnimeGenreEntity(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "mal_id")
    val malId: Int,

    // Other properties, not included because too long and might not related
)
```

And my cross reference:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "anime_genre_cross_reference",
    primaryKeys = ["anime_id", "genre_id"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = AnimeBasicEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["mal_id"],
            childColumns = ["anime_id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = AnimeGenreEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["mal_id"],
            childColumns = ["genre_id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
    ]
)
data class AnimeGenreCrossReference(

    @ColumnInfo(name = "anime_id", index = true)
    val animeId: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "genre_id", index = true)
    val genreId: Int
)
```

And i made a wrapper for return result like this:

```
data class AnimeFullEntity(

    @Embedded
    val anime: AnimeBasicEntity,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "mal_id",
        entityColumn = "mal_id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = AnimeGenreCrossReference::class,
            parentColumn = "anime_id",
            entityColumn = "genre_id"
        )
    )
    val genres: List<AnimeGenreEntity>
)
```

And here is my `DAO`:

```
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM anime WHERE mal_id =:malId LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getAnimeByAnimeId(malId: Int): AnimeFullEntity
```

I tried using `CROSS JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` like this:

```
    @Transaction
    @Query(
        "SELECT * FROM anime " +
                "CROSS JOIN anime_genre_cross_reference ON anime_id=:malId " +
                "WHERE mal_id =:malId"
    )
    suspend fun getAnimeByAnimeId(malId: Int): AnimeFullEntity
```

The query was success but there's some kind of non fatal error happening during query. And i can't seem to trace it because it says the location is out of my code lines(error happend on line 207 while my code is around 150). But, when i return to previous query, the query returning an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't appear that there is an issue with the query (see demo), rather the issue would appear to be observing the result from the suspended function.

However, there is no advantage in providing a query with the JOIN as Room will determine the Related `AnimeGenreEntity`s irrespective of any JOIN's specified, unless they impact the `AnimeBasicEntity`s returned.

- That is Room will extract the `AnimeBasicEntity`s according to the SQL then Room builds the `AnimeGenreEntity`s via a subquery retrieving ALL  that are related to the parent `AnimeBasicEnntity` being processed.

In addition to the probably needless JOIN you also have some unnecessary indexes.

- If the `@PrimaryKey` annotation is used on a field/column then a UNIQUE index is automatically created. As such both uses of `indices = [Index(value = ["mal_id"], unique = true)]` are unecessary.
- If `primaryKeys` is coded with the `@Entity` annotation there is no need to have an index of the first column as the primary key is indexed by the first column. An index on the second column is typically useful and Room will issue a warning in the build log if one is omitted.

Another aspect, which is probably not causing an issue, is that typically you JOIN based upon a column matching another column rather than a value.

- you have `SELECT * FROM anime CROSS JOIN anime_genre_cross_reference ON anime_id=:malId WHERE mal_id =:malId` when typically `SELECT * FROM anime CROSS JOIN anime_genre_cross_reference ON anime_id=mal_id WHERE mal_id =:malId` would be used.

  - The subtle difference, is the latter is `ON` the column `anime_id` equaling the column `mal_id` rather than the passed value `malId`

To demonstrate that your first, second and also the suggested (ON comparing columns) are effectively the same then perhaps consider the following `@Dao` interface:-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(animeBasicEntity: AnimeBasicEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(animeGenreEntity: AnimeGenreEntity): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(animeGenreCrossReference: AnimeGenreCrossReference): Long

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM anime WHERE mal_id =:malId LIMIT 1")
    /*suspend*/ fun getAnimeByAnimeId(malId: Int): AnimeFullEntity

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM anime CROSS JOIN anime_genre_cross_reference ON anime_id=mal_id WHERE mal_id =:malId")
    fun getAnimeByAnimeIdOther(malId: Int): AnimeFullEntity

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM anime CROSS JOIN anime_genre_cross_reference ON anime_id=:malId WHERE mal_id =:malId")
    fun getAnimeByAnimeIdOriginal(malId: Int): AnimeFullEntity
}
```

- NOTE suspend not used rather the main thread is used for brevity

Now also consider the following activity code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        val ab01id = dao.insert(AnimeBasicEntity(10))
        val ag01id = dao.insert(AnimeGenreEntity(100))
        val ag02id = dao.insert(AnimeGenreEntity(200))
        dao.insert(AnimeGenreCrossReference(ab01id.toInt(),ag01id.toInt()))
        dao.insert(AnimeGenreCrossReference(ab01id.toInt(),ag02id.toInt()))

        var af = dao.getAnimeByAnimeId(ab01id.toInt())
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        val sbg = StringBuilder()
        for (g in af.genres) {
            sbg.append("\n\t${g.malId}")
        }
        sb.append("STD AF has abid as ${af.anime.malId} and has ${af.genres.size} Genres. They are:-${sbg}")

        af = dao.getAnimeByAnimeIdOther(ab01id.toInt())
        sb.append("\n")
        sbg.delete(1,sbg.lastIndex+1)
        for (g in af.genres) {
            sbg.append("\n\t${g.malId}")
        }
        sb.append("OTH AF has abid as ${af.anime.malId} and has ${af.genres.size} Genres. They are:-${sbg}")

        af = dao.getAnimeByAnimeIdOriginal(ab01id.toInt())
        sb.append("\n")
        sbg.delete(1,sbg.lastIndex+1)
        for (g in af.genres) {
            sbg.append("\n\t${g.malId}")
        }
        sb.append("ORI AF has abid as ${af.anime.malId} and has ${af.genres.size} Genres. They are:-${sbg}")
        Log.d("DBINFO",sb.toString())
    }
}
```

When run (for the first time only) the following is output:-

```
D/DBINFO: STD AF has abid as 10 and has 2 Genres. They are:-
        100
        200
    OTH AF has abid as 10 and has 2 Genres. They are:-
    
        100
        200
    ORI AF has abid as 10 and has 2 Genres. They are:-
    
        100
        200
```

i.e. All 3 produce the same results.

> but there's some kind of non fatal error happening during query. And i can't seem to trace it because it says the location is out of my code lines(error happend on line 207 while my code is around 150).

This could be that the issue happened not in your code but in the code that Room generates.

Using the demo above then Room generates code (java) for both the `@Database` and the `@Dao` annotated classes. For example using Android View you can see, for example:-

[image]

- so the `@Database` annotated class suffixed with _Impl and likewise the `@Dao` annotated class(es) suffixed with _Impl.

The AllDAOs interface, for the `getAnimeByAnimeIdOriginal` function has the following code:-

```
@Override
  public AnimeFullEntity getAnimeByAnimeIdOriginal(final int malId) {
    final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM anime CROSS JOIN anime_genre_cross_reference ON anime_id=? WHERE mal_id =?";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 2);
    int _argIndex = 1;
    _statement.bindLong(_argIndex, malId);
    _argIndex = 2;
    _statement.bindLong(_argIndex, malId);
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, true, null);
      try {
        final int _cursorIndexOfMalId = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "mal_id");
        final LongSparseArray<ArrayList<AnimeGenreEntity>> _collectionGenres = new LongSparseArray<ArrayList<AnimeGenreEntity>>();
        while (_cursor.moveToNext()) {
          final long _tmpKey;
          _tmpKey = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfMalId);
          if (!_collectionGenres.containsKey(_tmpKey)) {
            _collectionGenres.put(_tmpKey, new ArrayList<AnimeGenreEntity>());
          }
        }
        _cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
        __fetchRelationshipgenreAsaASo77897338manytomanyAnimeGenreEntity(_collectionGenres);
        final AnimeFullEntity _result;
        if (_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          final AnimeBasicEntity _tmpAnime;
          final int _tmpMalId;
          _tmpMalId = _cursor.getInt(_cursorIndexOfMalId);
          _tmpAnime = new AnimeBasicEntity(_tmpMalId);
          final ArrayList<AnimeGenreEntity> _tmpGenresCollection;
          final long _tmpKey_1;
          _tmpKey_1 = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfMalId);
          _tmpGenresCollection = _collectionGenres.get(_tmpKey_1);
          _result = new AnimeFullEntity(_tmpAnime,_tmpGenresCollection);
        } else {
          _result = null;
        }
        __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        return _result;
      } finally {
        _cursor.close();
        _statement.release();
      }
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
    }
  }
```

- It can clearly be seen, amongst the spaghetti, that a Cursor is processed.
- However what is not as clear is the subsequent call to `__fetchRelationshipgenreAsaASo77897338manytomanyAnimeGenreEntity` *(note that the method name includes the package name)*. Which then does the underlying subquery which is equivalent of the JOIN based upon the `@Realtion` annotation. In this case the initial part of the query is

  "SELECT `genre`.`mal_id` AS `mal_id`,_junction.`anime_id` FROM `anime_genre_cross_reference` AS _junction INNER JOIN `genre` ON (_junction.`genre_id` = `genre`.`mal_id`) WHERE _junction.`anime_id` IN ("

  ```
    - the remainder, the IN clause is built and appended
  ```
- note the `'s enclosing the component names (columns/tables) are lost in the above.

What you could do is ignore the warning about editing the _Impl class and put a breakpoint and then run in debug mode e.g.:-

[image]

In the above you can see that there are the expected 2 Genres and that they have the expected values of 100 and 200, when the breakpoint is placed on line 256 of the AllDAOs_Impl class which equates to line 95 or thereabouts in the source code.